# Check box is not getting value in Syncfusion Angular shedular

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I have applied custom form in Angular scheduler. I have used Checkbox on that form.
Screen shot : https://prnt.sc/pu29ec 
I used this code to render checkbox:

```
<tr *ngFor="let a of packageList"> 
      <td colspan="2" > 
    <ejs-checkbox id="{{a.Value}}" name="{{a.Text}}" value="{{data[a.Text]}}"  label="{{a.Text}}" [checked]="a.Text==data.Package"></ejs-checkbox> 
                                    </td> 
                                                                            </tr>
```

but when I checked  checkbox and submit the form it is not taking value. It should receive data.Package  = true 
Sceen shot: https://prnt.sc/pu2ch5

Is there any mistake from my code? or please give me guide how to apply checkbox on shedular form.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation of Syncfusion you need to bind it as [checked] = "true" or [checked] = "false". Here is the [example](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/check-box/how-to/customized-checkbox/?_ga=2.193714857.547122220.1573219660-309904773.1573219660) about it. Can you please try as the documentation.

Comment: I have used [checked]="a.Text==data.Package" if match  checkbox become true when loading form but on submit not getting value.

Comment: Also the problem is can be on the value attribute of checkbox. @AbulHasan

Comment: No there is no console error. The value is not initialized in data . see screen shot https://prnt.sc/pu2ch5 Please notice.. I have used it on shedular

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion Greetings.

We provided the ‘e-field’ support only for limited JS2 Syncfusion components like datepicker, datetimepicker, dropdownlist, multiselect, checkbox and input components . For other JS2 components and angular material component, you have to handle the ‘getting and setting the values to those fields’ in sample end using actionBegin and popupOpen event.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h231v1-phrybr?file=app.component.ts

Regards, 
M.Vinitha devi.